# What has the higher probability: everyone picks the same thing or every thing is picked by the same number of people?

Tags: probability

There are $ 20 $ people at an ice cream shop.
Each one chooses from $4$ flavours.

(Suppose that none of the decisions each one make influences other's decisions and wont run out of ice cream.)

Which one is more likely to happen?

A: Everyone picks the same flavour.

B: Every flavour is picked by $5$ people.

For A my guess: Everyone can make a decision to chose one from $4$, and there are $20$ people so:
$\frac{1}{4}^{20}$

Can someone help me with B?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can represent the flavours that are chosen by a sequence of $20$ numbers each between $1$ and $4$. The first number represents the flavour chosen by the first person, the second number represents the flavour chosen by the second person etc.

There are $4^{20}$ such sequences.

Of these $4^{20}$ sequences, just $4$ are sequences in which everyone chooses the same flavour, so all the numbers in the sequence are the same. So the chances of everyone choosing the same flavour are $4$ in $4^{20}$ or $1$ in $4^{19}$.

On the other hand, if each flavour is picked  by five people then there are $\binom{20}{5}$ ways of picking five people from $20$ - let's say these five people all choose flavour $1$. This leaves $15$ people, and there are $\binom{15}{5}$ ways of picking five people from $15$ - let's say these five people all choose flavour $2$.

Continuing like this, we can see that the number of sequences in which each flavour is chosen by five people is

$\binom{20}{5}\binom{15}{5}\binom{10}{5}\binom{5}{5} = \frac{20!}{(5!)^4}$

This is clearly much greater than $4$. So it is much more likely that each flavour is picked by five people than that everyone chooses the same flavour.

Answer (score 0):

A is wrong as is pointed out in comments to this answer. For B I suggest you considering first finding probablility of that one flavour is choosen exactly by 5 people. Then the same, but considering that only 3 flavours and 15 people remains. Multiplying these two will give probability that 2 flavours are chosen by 5 people each. Continue the same way until all flavours are chosen.

UPD: If I am not miscalculated probablity that exactly 5 people choose one flavor is probabity that no one chooses this flavor subtracted from probabity that 15 people do not choose this flavor
$$(\frac{3}{4})^{15} - (\frac{3}{4})^{20} = (\frac{3}{4})^{15}\frac{4^5-3^5}{4^5} = \frac{3^{15} \cdot 781}{4^{20}}$$

Comment: You may wish to edit your answer - A is wrong.  Should be computed as either $4 \times \left(\frac{1}{4}\right)^{[20]}$ re any of the 4 flavors can be *involved* or $\left(\frac{1}{4}\right)^{[19]}$ re the first choice (of 20) should be *ignored*, since this choice **decides** the flavor.

Comment: Indeed, thank you for pointing that out.